# Xcode - trying to work with multiple files but failing

Tags: c++, xcode

I am completely new to Xcode! Trying to create a c++ project with multiple files but the functions in them cannot be found by main. My conclusion is the files have not been added to the project properly. When I use the command File > Add files to "project name"... it is impossible to select the files I want to add. I can find them in the navigator but not select and add them to the project. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are these c++ files? You should be able to add any file to the project using your approach, but Xcode does detect c++ source and header files by extension and add then to the target. If that is your problem, then you can add them yourself to the target (provided that that makes sense) by clicking the target membership checkbox in the right (Utilities) pane for each file added.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! They already have the right target membership according to the panel. Maybe that is why they cannot be added! However, they are still not found by main... Could there be something else I have missed?

Comment: What do you mean when you say they are not found by main? What errors are you getting when you **build**? Are these files header files or source files? If source are they not being compiled and therefore you have missing symbol errors when linking?

Comment: It told me there was no matching function but when I made a new project it suddenly worked. Must have changed something without noticing. Well thanks for helping :) now I know how to check target membership for next time!